# Ошибка при подключении к Long Poll серверу VK

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу написать своего чат-бота для ВК. Пишу на Python, библиотека - vk_api. Написал такой вот код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

token = 'my_token'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, myGroupId)
```

Данный код выкидывает следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/PC/Documents/my_documents/Программирование/VKBot/bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, myGroupId)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Documents\my_documents\Программирование\VKBot\env\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.update_longpoll_server()
  File "C:\Users\PC\Documents\my_documents\Программирование\VKBot\env\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 231, in update_longpoll_server    
    response = self.vk.method('groups.getLongPollServer', values)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Documents\my_documents\Программирование\VKBot\env\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

В настройках группы все включил(сообщения сообщества, возможности ботов, LongPoll API).

В качестве токена использую ключ доступа, который создается в настройках самой группы.
Как мне исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

[VK API Возвращаемы ошибки](https://vk.com/dev/errors)

> 15 Доступ запрещён.
>   Убедитесь, что Вы используете верные идентификаторы, и доступ к контенту для текущего пользователя есть в полной версии сайта.

Для того чтобы подключить к LongPool необходимо передать токен и идентификатор группы.

Видимо вы либо что-то не так настроили в настройках группы либо в программе указали неверный токен или id группы.